# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord task belongs to company & has_many users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and was wonder if this is a good setup, or if there is a better configuration.

Background: 
The system will be used to assign tasks to users, track the assignor, and allow multiple people to be assigned the task.

**Create a company model, user model, task model, and a user_tasks model.**
Company Class 
has_many :users
has_many :tasks

User Class
belongs_to :company
has_many :user_tasks
has_many :tasks, through: :user_tasks

Task Class
belongs_to :company
has_many :user_tasks
has_many :users, through: :user_tasks

UserTasks Class
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :task
*Tracks assignor with boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is perfect. There is one big advantage of having a `has_many (model1), through: (model2)` association when compared to `has_and_belongs_to_many` association in that you can access the join model (`UserTasks` your case) through the ActiveRecord query interface (`UserTask.where()` or `UserTask.find_by(user_id: 1)` and so forth). Querying the join table directly can sometimes shorten your queries. If you use the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association you will have a database table that you cannot directly access in Rails without resorting to SQL.

Comment: Hey Raoul, when you say "you have database table that you cannot access in Rails without resorting to SQL", what do you mean/can you give an example? Are these for when you build a Rails app on an existing database?

Comment: Hi Daryll, what I mean is that with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship you can obviously query the `User` table from the `Task` table, using `User.tasks` for example, but to access the join table you would need to run an SQL query like this: `User.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN user_tasks ON users.id = user_tasks.user_id")`. Regarding an existing databases I think it should be possible to put a `has_many: .. through: ..` association on top of an existing database as long as the join table is there and the names of the join model in Rails and SQL match up.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need the UserTasks class if it is just a habtm table.  So just create a migration for that table, but skip adding the model.  Then in `User`, do `has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks` and in `Task` do `has_and_belongs_to_many :users`

The other thing that I see is that company is set for both tasks and users.  You might have business rules to why this has to be, but if not, you might just be able to say `Company -> has_many :tasks, through: :users`

Comment: You have a point, but what if they need a new column on the specific "UserTask". For example, I can be assigned to a Task twice, one as a programmer and another time as a designer. So I need some kind of "JobDescription" column on the UserTask column, and I'd need two rows of the UserTask table to represent me being a programmer on a task, and another to represent me being a designer on a task.

Comment: Daryll- correct.  If it is JUST a habtm table, then the class is not needed, but if storing any other data, then the intermediate class will need to be there.

Comment: Hi Brandon - The only issue I have with using HABTM is that I need to track who originally assigned the task to other individuals.  Also, I agree with Daryll, I may need to update the UserTask table to include additional criteria. I have the company_id being stored in the event we need to delete (fire) the user_id from the relationship table...we would still want the task to exist, allowing us to reassign to another user.

Comment: That's fine.  Was just a suggestion (and with the qualifier of "if it is just a habtm...")

Comment: No worries. I think I spent way too much time on the [has_many, :through](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/) blog. [Start here](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/2/28/association-goodness), it's so cool how 2014 Rails looks similar to 2006 Rails.

Comment: Yeah, overall the API has remained pretty constant, while, IMO still improving in meaningful ways.

Comment: Brandon - I appreciated the suggestion.  Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I favor `:has_many, :through` over `has_many_and_belongs_to_many` or HABTM.  For example, I can be assigned to a Task twice, one as a programmer and another time as a designer. So I need some kind of "JobDescription" column on the UserTask column, and I'd need two rows of the UserTask table to represent me being a programmer on a task, and another to represent me being a designer on a task.

You want to write software that is easier to change, even though HABTM is shorter, you might change the software in the future, like in the case of a person doing two subtasks in the same task. Remember that a row in a database is a piece of data, or "a thing", if that makes sense. At the very least, you get timestamps.